# Update clarity 1.0 issue

Tags: vmware-clarity

I am using Angular v6.0.0 and clarity v12.0 , now I am trying to update Angular to v7.00 and clarity v1.0.0, I am just change the version numbers in my package.json file, Then enter the npm install.

after that i found some build errors(like forRoot() deprecated) i was fix them, but some of build errors coming like '/node_modules/@clr/angular/clr-angular"' has no exported member 'Wizard'.', I am verify my node modules folder @clr folder it is have empty folders..it mean clarity is not installed by this npm install...

so can you please provide the update steps.

Comment: all deprecated names for components were removed. You can find the complete list here: https://vmware.github.io/clarity/news/0.11.0-rc.1. Did you use update Clarity with the angular cli? It should have given you a warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all deprecated names for components were removed. You can find the complete list here: vmware.github.io/clarity/news/0.11.0-rc.1. Did you use update Clarity with the angular cli? It should have given you a warning

-hippeelee